# Accessing pyramid views using knockout js

Tags: javascript, python, knockout.js, pyramid, mako

I have this `delete` view in ***Pyramid*** and I'm using **mako** templates and **knockout js**.

```
config.add_route('delete', '/delete/{id}')
```

This is my route to `delete` view in pyramid. I want to bind some buttons in the template to this url so that it invokes the `delete` view.

I've tried doing it as:

```
<script>
this.delete = function(detail){

  $.post(
      "${request.route_url('delete', id=detail['id'])}",
      {'action' : 'delete', 'id' : detail.id()},
      function(response){

          //remove the currently selected detail from the array
          self.details.remove(detail);
      }
  );
};
```

However this returns the following **traceback**:

```
TypeError: 'Undefined' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

1. What is the correct way of doing this?
2. The `delete` view has `location` set to the current page. So is there a way to do this without refreshing the current page?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the answer. I'm adding this for future Googlers.

The values must be made observable as `ko.observable('<some_value>')` in the **knockout** model so that they are updated without refreshing.

The link should have been like `delete/<some_id>`. So concatenate the strings `"delete/"` and the `id` from the json object as:

`var delete_link = "delete/".concat(detail.id);`

Then use the delete function as follows:

```
this.delete = function(detail){
   var delete_link = "delete/".concat(detail.id);
   $.post(
      delete_link,
      {'action' : 'delete', 'id' : detail['id']},
      function(response){
          self.details.remove(detail);
          }   
       );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`${request.route_url('delete', id=detail['id'])}` is python/mako code, not javascript code. If your ID were 99, it should ultimately render to html as `delete/99`.

You are getting the TypeError in python because there is no object/variable in the template namespace called `detail`. Perhaps this is because you have called it record or something when you passed the arguments into mako? You haven't included enough information for me to tell...

If you passed into mako `detail={id:99}`, then `${request.route_url('delete', id=detail['id'])}` would work. If detail were an object, then `detail.id` would be more appropriate.

Further to this though, you may be better off defining a javascript object **in mako** like this (presuming I've passed an object into mako as the variable 'mako_object');

```
var my_object = {
    id: ${mako_object.id},
    delete_url: "${request.route_url('delete', id=mako_object.id)}",
}
```

and thus the html would look like;

```
var my_object = {
    id: 99,
    delete_url: "/delete/99",
}
```